# How to specify a range instead of using .EntireRow in vba

Tags: excel, vba

This line of code copies an entire row but I want to specify a range to copy instead.

```
Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Copy
```

How do I specify a range to copy?

Comment: With Worksheets().Range()?

Comment: Sorry I don't  really understand. Do you mean 'Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").Range ().Copy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheets("MasterSheet").Range(Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(2, 2)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(10, 10)
```

This will copy range A1:B2 to J10

the cells command take numbers corresponding to row and column numbers, so cells(1,1) is A1, cells (2,2) is B2.

Putting two cells inside a range command defines a range bounded by the two cells

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer already given, `.Range(.Cells(i, "C"), .Cells(row , column))` , it is worth noting you can specify alternate ranges by manipulating the range you already have.

Note: I am using `Worksheets` collection, not `Sheets` collection, as Sheets collection may include Chart sheet objects.

This:

```
Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C")
```

Will be a single cell in column C, row i.

**Resize:**

You can expand this range with `startrange.Resize(numberOfRows,numberOfColumns)`

For example:

```
Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").Resize(1,2)
```

The above is now 1 row by 2 columns.

**Offset:**

You could also shift this range with `startrange.OFFSET(numberOfRows,numberOfColumns)`

For example:

```
Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").Offset(1,1)
```

This shifts 1 row down, 1 column across.

**Offset and Resize:**

And you can chain these command together with `startCell.OFFSET(numberOfRows,numberOfColumns).Resize(numberOfRows,numberOfColumns)`

For example:

```
Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(i, "C").Offset(1, 1).Resize(1, 2)
```

Showing that with code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    With Worksheets("MasterSheet")
        Debug.Print .Cells(i, "C").Address
        Debug.Print .Cells(i, "C").Resize(1, 2).Address
        Debug.Print .Cells(i, "C").Offset(1, 1).Address
        Debug.Print .Cells(i, "C").Offset(1, 1).Resize(1, 2).Address
    End With

End Sub
```

Gives:

[image: Specifying ranges]

Reading:

1. [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel)
2. [Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-resize-property-excel)

Comment: Thanks a whole lot